# PysimpleGui button not working when nested

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Here's my code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout1 = [[sg.Button('New', "center")], [sg.Button("Load Save", "center")]]
layout2 = [[sg.Text("2nd Page")], [sg.Button("New Page", "center")], [sg.Button("Load Page", "center")]]

layout = [[sg.Column(layout1, key='-COL1-'), sg.Column(layout2, visible=False, key='-COL2-')]]

window = sg.Window('ORIGINAL').Layout(layout)

while True:             # Event Loop
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event in (None, 'Exit'):
        break
    if event == 'New':
        print("hello")
    elif event == '2':
        print("hello 2")
window.Close()
```

When I click on the buttons nothing happens.
If I put those buttons inside the layout (instead of layout1 or layout2) they work perfectly.
So my question is how can I get those buttons to work while leaving them where they are?

Sorry if it is a dumb question, I am pretty new to pysimplegui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not about where the button elements, but what arguments you provided to `sg.Button`.

`sg.Button` is defined as

```py
class Button(Element):
    """
    Button Element - Defines all possible buttons. The shortcuts such as Submit, FileBrowse, ... each create a Button
    """

    def __init__(self, button_text='', button_type=BUTTON_TYPE_READ_FORM, target=(None, None), tooltip=None,
                 file_types=(("ALL Files", "*.*"),), initial_folder=None, default_extension='', disabled=False, change_submits=False,
                 enable_events=False, image_filename=None, image_data=None, image_size=(None, None),
                 image_subsample=None, border_width=None, size=(None, None), s=(None, None), auto_size_button=None, button_color=None,
                 disabled_button_color=None,
                 highlight_colors=None, mouseover_colors=(None, None), use_ttk_buttons=None, font=None, bind_return_key=False, focus=False, pad=None, key=None,
                 k=None, right_click_menu=None, expand_x=False, expand_y=False, visible=True, metadata=None):
```

Keyword omitted when you passed arguments to `sg.Button`, second argument will be `button_type`, not sure why you gave a `'center'`. Besides `button_text`, `key` or `key`, it is clear that there's no any other argument can be with such a value `'center'`.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout1 = [
    [sg.Button('New')],
    [sg.Button('Load')],
    [sg.Button('Save')],
]

layout2 = [
    [sg.Text("2nd Page")],
    [sg.Button("New Page")],
    [sg.Button("Load Page")],
]

layout = [
    [sg.Column(layout1, key='-COL1-'),
     sg.Column(layout2, visible=False, key='-COL2-')],
]

window = sg.Window('ORIGINAL', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event  == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'New':
        print("Hello New")
    elif event == 'Load':
        print("Hello Load")
    elif event == 'Save':
        print("Hello Save")

window.close()
```